# Any indexed color mapping features in CSS?

Tags: css, colormap, palette, indexed

When creating graphics in GIMP I often make several versions of graphics (like game characters with different outfits) using indexed color mode in the .png file where I develop the images so I can change the appearance of the graphics by just changing out the color values in the palette.

Now imagine being able to use this indexed color map concept at runtime.

I was wondering if CSS3 may contain functionality for real-time indexed color mapping. One where you can change the appearance of a displayed image on the fly by simply changing the color values in an indexed palette.

Right now I am using Mojave's version of Safari on my macbook.

Comment: No, CSS does not support this. I am sure you can program this tough with Canvas. But that's nothing "out of the box".

Comment: Impossible with CSS to alter PNGs like this, but you can use custom properties at runtime to store color values and dynamically change many elements with one variable essentially